# Use data-toggle to get a variable name and use that variable name in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to switch out an iframe for an image and do so with a minimum of code.

My container div is using data-toggle

```
<div id="my-div" data-toggle="video2">
    <div id="videocontainer">
        <img src="my-image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my sites script file I am using this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(".my-div[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
            var video2 = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/></iframe>'
            var slctr = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding selector from data-toggle
            var innerhtml = (slctr);
            $("#videocontainer").html(innerhtml);

        });

    });
});
```

This will load the data-toggle contents into the window but not the var. Not sure why as I am totally new to this.

How do I use a variable retrieved from the code to switch the html and also can i use data-id instead of data-toggle or could it be data-anything.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You say $(".my-div .. where you should have $("#my-div ..  Or forget the id/class and simply look for the data attribute: $('[data-toggle]')

Comment: Sorry null for the confusion I was looking to change the image contained in a div with a youtube video. I also wanted to use the same few lines of code for all of the images>video instead of writing a new function for each vimage>video.

Comment: Thanks for your input Julian, you are correct that was a typo in my post. My code is written how you suggested. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var innerhtml = eval(slctr);
```

This will evaluate the javascript expression contained in the variable `slctr`. If that variable contains just the name of your variable (as in this case), it will evaluate to the value of that variable, which (I believe) is what you're looking for.

And yes, you can use `data-<anything>`

Comment: This worked PERFECT! Thank you so much! I got it all to work and changed it to load to a class... that dint work to well as it loaded the video to all of the divs that are set to that class (DOH)... supposed to be 3 videos loading to 3 separate divs.

So I created another data-<anything> and used ?(this).data("<anything>"); to get the corresponding div also! Works like a charm.

Now I want to figure out how switch back to the image when the video stops playing. Not a question though, want to give it a shot first.

Thanks again for your help!